# How can you list the secondary branches with the github API?

Tags: java, github

I'm using the org.eclipse.egit.github.core api with Java. But I have not found anywhere like from a given repository I can list all the branches that it has inside.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the source code, it looks like in the RepositoryService class [there is a method](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/RepositoryService.java#L795-L813) for pulling all of the branches of a repository. Based on their sample code, I think a request would look like this:

```
RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService();
RepositoryId repo = new RepositoryId("rails", "rails");
for (RepositoryBranch branch : service.getBranches(repo))
  System.out.println(branch.getName());
```